# Postgresql query placement of where causes different results

Tags: postgresql

I have two versions of the same query that I would expect to return the same results, but the results are different.

Query 1:

```
select * from erp_data.invoices i
left join
(select * from erp_data.invoice_extra_data where data_key = 'job_number') d
using(invoice_id)
where customer_no = '6357' and (data_key = 'job_number' or data_key is null)
and (customer_purchase_order_no ilike '%newtown%' or customer_purchase_order_no ilike '%newtown%' or customer_purchase_order_no ilike '%newton%')
and (order_date >= '2017-09-01' and order_date < '2017-11-01')
```

Query 2:

```
select * from erp_data.invoices i
left join erp_data.invoice_extra_data d
using(invoice_id)
where customer_no = '6357' and (data_key = 'job_number' or data_key is null)
and (customer_purchase_order_no ilike '%newtown%' or customer_purchase_order_no ilike '%newtown%' or customer_purchase_order_no ilike '%newton%')
and (order_date >= '2017-09-01' and order_date < '2017-11-01')
```

It looks like postgresql first does the join, and then applies the where cause to the join.  I say this because all items in the invoice table have SOMETHING in the invoice_extra_data table, but not all invoices have something with data_key = 'job_number', so the two queries return different results.

Specifically, invoices that do not have an entry in the invoice_extra_data table with data_key = 'job_number' are excluded by the second query.  One could interpret the expected results as, "show such an invoice, because of the left join" or, "reject such an invoice, because it fails the, "where" clause".

Does postgresql ALWAYS do the join before applying the filters in the where portion of the query?

Comment: Did you have a look at the output of EXPLAIN?

Comment: The, "EXPLAIN" produced results that looked the same for both queries.  I ran "EXPLAIN" in the query browser and looked at the pictures they produced - I didn't look at the raw text from explain.

Comment: You introduced two table aliases, `d` and `i` . Now, please **use** them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I say this because all items in the invoice table have SOMETHING in
>   the invoice_extra_data table, but not all invoices have something with
>   data_key = 'job_number'

So let's say you have a record in erp_data.invoice_extra_data `where data_key = 'other_id'`.

In the first query this record is excluded during the initial left join because of the `WHERE` statement.  Then you later check to see if the value is either 'job_number' or NULL and, because it was excluded, it's NULL.  It passes and will be included.

In the second query this record is NOT excluded during the initial left join because it doesn't have the `WHERE` statement.  Later you check to see if the value is either 'job_number' or NULL and, because it was NOT excluded, it's 'other_id'.  It will now not pass and will not be included.

Your first query, if you wish to simplify it, could also be written as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM erp_data.invoices i
    LEFT JOIN erp_data.invoice_extra_data d ON i.invoice_id=d.invoice_id 
        AND data_key = 'job_number'
WHERE customer_no = '6357' 
    AND (customer_purchase_order_no ilike '%newtown%' 
            OR customer_purchase_order_no ilike '%newtown%'
            OR customer_purchase_order_no ilike '%newton%')
    AND order_date >= '2017-09-01' 
    AND order_date < '2017-11-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Q: Does postgresql ALWAYS do the join before applying the filters in the
>   where portion of the query?

Yes, as documented in [`The WHERE clause`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#queries-where):

> After the processing of the FROM clause is done, each row of the
>   derived virtual table is checked against the search condition. If the
>   result of the condition is true, the row is kept in the output table,
>   otherwise (i.e., if the result is false or null) it is discarded.